# Do photons exist at all possible wavelengths?

Tags: electromagnetic-radiation, photons, thermal-radiation, frequency, wavelength

My question refers to Photon flux spectrum diagrams.

The diagram shows the number of photons at different wavelengths. My question is whether the graph is granular or continuous. Do photons exist at all possible wavelengths, or are there some "forbidden" wavelengths?

--- I want to get a PFD data set but not sure how to treat the 0.5 nm increments in the https://www.nrel.gov/grid/solar-resource/spectra.html (G173-03) Spectral data.

Below my calcuations are in green. I am afraid I am double counting photons the way ive done it so far.

(small note the coloumn D should say PFD and not PPFD*)

[image]

[image]

Comment: It is possible to have a single photon with a non-well-defined wavelength whose spectrum spans an interval, you know.

Comment: That's an interesting question! For a given source there are of course wavelengths that are forbidden (e.g. only certain transitions exist in an atom, etc), and you always have the option to make a pulse shorter (thereby "stretching" it across wavelengths), or move the source. Hence I don't immediately see a reason why it shouldn't be possible to have photons of arbitrary wavelength. It would be interesting to see if there is an upper or lower limit.

Comment: However, it is possibly a duplicate of [How many possible electromagnetic wavelengths are possible?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/305576/how-many-possible-electromagnetic-wavelengths-are-possible)

Comment: @ahemmetter please see amendments.

Comment: With the treatment of a black body there is no granularity. I see this convuloted. Even a molecular spectrum is truly continuous either because duration / E relation or internal and external interactions.  Except for going down to Plank length as in the, otherwise different, mentioned question. The latter is not per se a duplicate but I suspect it is the same at the core level.

Comment: Are you interested in all photons *from the Sun*, or all photons in general? With regards to your recent edit, the wavelength doesn't need to be a multiple of a nanometer; 373.0nm and 373.5nm are different photons with different energies. In fact there are photons with a wavelength of only a fraction of a nanometer, e.g. gamma rays have wavelength in the picometer range. It just depends if your spectrometer can resolve such small differences in wavelength.

Comment: This question has an obvious and unhelpful answer. Any wavelengths that are forbidden are not possible. Thus, even in the case of there being forbidden wavelengths, the set of all wavelengths at which photons exist is the set of all possible wavelengths. Therefore, yes, photons exist at all possible wavelengths

Answer (score 2):

> Do photons exist at all possible wavelengths?

Yes. You can essentially treat the background illumination as a full continuum over wavelength, such that any arbitrary wavelength interval, no matter how small, will contain a nonzero amount of energy.

For data sets like the one that underlies the plot in your image, if it is reported at a regular grid in wavelength (i.e. values of photon spectral flux at each wavelength in the list $\lambda_0$, $\lambda_0+\Delta\lambda$, $\lambda_0+2\Delta\lambda$, $\lambda_0+3\Delta\lambda$, $\ldots$), then the standard assumption will be that this represents the integrated spectral photon flux over an interval of length $\Delta\lambda$ around the reported wavelenght, i.e. the reported spectral photon flux at $\lambda_0+n\Delta \lambda$ is the integral of the spectral photon flux over the interval $[\lambda_0+(n-\tfrac12\Delta \lambda),\lambda_0+(n+\tfrac12\Delta \lambda)]$, divided by $\Delta \lambda$.

However, it's always possible that the dataset you're working with is doing something fancier - in which case this will be specified in detail in the dataset's associated documentation.

Comment: photons do not have wavelengths, they have frequencies. The wavelength is hidden in the complex wavefunction and is not measurable except in probability distributions. The energy is measurable.

Comment: @annav As far as the formalism here is concerned, $\lambda$ is by definition $c/\nu$, regardless of how you choose to interpret it. If it has a frequency, then it has a wavelength for all practical purposes regarding the measurements OP asks about.

Answer (score 1):

Photons  are quantum entities, they are elementary point particles of energy= $hν$ where h is the Planck constant and $ν$ the frequency of the wave that will be built up when photons of this frequency are accumulated, the emergent classical electromagnetic wave. For single photon behavior see [this double slit single photon experiment.](https://www.sps.ch/en/articles/progresses/wave-particle-duality-of-light-for-the-classroom-13/). The accumulated interference pattern is a measure of probability distribution of the photons impinging on the double slits.

The wavelength corresponding to  the $ν$ is mathematically within the complex valued wave function of the photon, and can be seen only in probability distributions. As energy has only the limit of conservation of energy, values of frequencies can go from zero to infinity, bounded by the possibility of having an appropriate source, and so do the wavelengths of the emergent classical light beams.

As said in  the comments [black body radiation](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/mod6.html) has no limit, except on how probable it is for a very low or very high energy photon to be emitted .

The figure you are describing is a transmission (label  on the right) figure too, so the material interposed will limit by absorption the photon frequencies that can be transmitted.The spectra seen are absorptions from atomic and molecular levels of the transmitter.

Comment: Single photons need not have a well-defined frequency, in exactly the same way that single electrons need not have a well-defined energy.

Comment: Or, to lay out the reasoning more expansively: in QFT, photons and electrons have exactly the same status (i.e. excitations of a quantum field), and electrons can have non-well-defined energy. In order to claim that all photons need to have well-defined frequencies, you need to be claiming that (i) photons and electrons are not equivalent in QFT (and if so, how?) or (ii) that QFT somehow does not apply to photons.

Comment: @EmilioPisanty I am evidently talking about measurable photons, not about virtual or other theoretical photons, because the plot in the question is measured photons. Dragging in the formalism of quantum field theory on such an elementary question is not useful, imo of course. Basic quantum mechanics, which always holds no matter higher level mathematical complications, should answer measurement questions.

Comment: Quantum field theory can be applied to everything, I have been taught of a QFT of nuclear physics, it is a formalism. When photons do not have a well defined frequency, they are off mass shell in the corresponding QFT feynman diagrams, i.e.virtual.

Comment: It is perfectly possible to have an on-shell, fully physical single-photon state without a well-defined frequency - simply take a superposition of multiple states with different frequencies.

Comment: @EmilioPisanty  it is a wave packet representation, a probability distribution, but if you measure it , one frequency will come up.

Comment: **If** you perform a projective measurement on frequency, then yes, that will collapse the wavefunction into a single frequency. But if you measure any observable that does not commute with it (say, time-binning) then you will be completely unable to make such an assignment. Superpositions in QM, as you know, are not probability distributions over properties which the system "has" to begin with.

Comment: @EmilioPisanty  I am a "direct measurement" person, ofcourse if one uses a probabilistic mathematical model to go from one measurement to another  one has to take care to use the correct  functions.As an experimentalist  I tend to see physics as measurements fitted by models and not as models generating  data :)

Comment: @ Anna With respect - you're missing the point. There are multiple, incompatible, possible measurements, just like with position and momentum of a particle. QM does not allow statements that say a system "has" a property until and unless you perform a projective measurement of that property. A photon in a wavepacket cannot be ascribed a frequency (or a time bin) until and unless you measure frequency (resp. time of arrival), in exactly the same way that electrons don't have trajectories.

Comment: In short: QM is not a "model". You don't get to ignore core parts of the theory by talking about "direct measurement", whatever that means.

Comment: @EmilioPisanty by "use the correct functions" I did include thhe Heisenberg uncertainty. The probability distributions predicted by quantum mechanics are also measurements, and for me, all theories, classical and quantum mechanical model the behavior of the data/measurements and are predictive for new ones. It is the measurements that "exist". . Obviously we differ on this pov .

Comment: The claims in this answer and your comments here are in as deep a conflict with the fundamentals of QM as saying "the electrons in the 1s state of hydrogen have circular orbits". But perhaps we do disagree on the basic principle that one shouldn't make statements that QM explicitly designates as unphysical and counter-factual.