# How do we define a color?

Tags: optics, visible-light

Is Black a color or just the absence of others colors/light . What actually constituents colors? How do we define if something is a color or not?

Comment: Related: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/19690 ; https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/24263

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What are colors?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/24263/)

Comment: Color is subjective term, usually color maps to some light frequency range. But also color depends on sensitivity of human photoreceptor cells. Bear in mind that some people do not see colors correctly at all {see [Color blindness](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Color_blindness)} as well as some animals only see in a [grayscale](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/28478/do-animals-exist-which-have-good-vision-but-see-only-grayscale) (shade of darkness).

Comment: Depends who you ask. A printer or a painter would tell you that black is a color. A physicist would say, "no."

Comment: [What is Gray, from a physics POV?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/339130/37364)